# ListCtrl in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

How to use timer with ListCtrl??(i want to clear all items in List then add items in List to every 2 second ...)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple example:

```
import wx
import time

TIMER_ID = wx.NewId()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lstctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                   size=(250,300),
                                   style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.lstctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Date", width=200)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.lstctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

        wx.EVT_TIMER(self, TIMER_ID, self.OnTimer)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, TIMER_ID)
        self.timer.Start(2000)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        self.lstctrl.InsertStringItem(self.lstctrl.GetItemCount(), 
                                      time.asctime())

app=wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```